# Stats question to compound drop off

Tags: statistics

Let say we have a population of 1,000 people. Let say we wanted to know the death rate out of the population in a period of 100 years.

The thing I want is something to describe probability of someone making it to year x and being alive all through year x.

So for columns we have years, dead, alive, don't know.

If someone dies then in the years the population decreases. But, let say we don't know if someone has died in a particular year so it would be in don't know. But, in the year after we would know if they had died.

Is there some way of working out probability of a person being alive at year x given we know what happen over 100 years with that constraint of don't know people?

Sorry if this sounds vague. For the probability of being alive on year x I would normally take say number known people alive in year x / (people alive in year x + people died in year x). However, this does not take into account the known people in the year and also it doesn't really show that the population has decreased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each year $x$, you have a probability that a "don't know" at year $x$ died in year $x$, and a probability that they died in year $x+1$ instead. This just gives you a convolution of your distribution P(died at year x) = P(know that they certainly died in year x) + P(they survived until year x and resulted in "dont know")*P(they died in year x given that they were "dont know" in year x)